# How to improve perfomance of PL/SQL UTL_FILE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the requirement to export up to 200 million blobs from oracle database to linux based directory as images. Once the images are exported to the directory, Oracle Web Center batchloader then ingest those images to oracle web center content. The code below try to achieve main objectives.

1. It select blob columns from the given table then extract those blob columns into flat file
2. it then record all the exported images to image_log3 table. All the image_log3 table contents will used to generate the batchloader input file.
3. All failed images are recorded into image_null_log3 table and all the times it took to export images from start to finish is recorded in table time_log .

**Problem:**

The code is taking too long to run. Currently to export 100000 blobs and write to file takes 10.9 and to export 10000 it takes 0.5.

I am already using bulk collect, optimizer hints. How can I improve this code to achieve faster performance to be able to export and write as many images to the flat file as possible?

Please advice

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY OWCMIGRATION.biometric_blob_to_file_april28
 AS

    /*
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Procedure Name: write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26
    Procedure Description: This procedure is used to convert blob data into image file.
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    PROCEDURE write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26( ls_pin_ref VARCHAR2, ls_msisdn VARCHAR2,l_blob BLOB, ls_file_name VARCHAR2)
    AS

       lclob_file              CLOB;
       ln_cursor_cnt        NUMBER := 0;
       t_blob                  BLOB;
       l_file               UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
       t_TotalSize          NUMBER;
       t_file_name         VARCHAR2 (100);
       t_remain             NUMBER;
       t_position            NUMBER := 1;
       l_buffer               RAW(32760);--VARCHAR2(32760);--
       l_amount             BINARY_INTEGER := 32760;
       err_code              VARCHAR2(10);
       err_msg               VARCHAR2(250);


    BEGIN

        DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (lclob_file, TRUE);

        --Incrementing the cursor count and the commit count for eacj record being processed.
          ln_cursor_cnt := ln_cursor_cnt + 1;

        --Calculationg length and getting file name of the image*/

         SELECT DBMS_LOB.getlength  (l_blob)    BLOB_BASE64,    ls_file_name
            INTO t_TotalSize, t_file_name
            FROM DUAL
            WHERE nvl(length(dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob)),0)<>0; 


        --If length of blob is not null then inserting into image log table for generating config file*/   
            IF t_TotalSize <>0 THEN

                INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL */ INTO Image_Log3
                    VALUES(ls_pin_ref,ls_msisdn,ls_file_name);

                COMMIT;

            END IF;

        --Opening File in Write mode in directory migration2
        l_file :=      UTL_FILE.fopen ('ECM_MIGRATION_QA',  t_file_name, 'wb',  32767); --BIO_MIGRATION_QA
          t_remain := t_TotalSize;

        --Converting Blob into Images

--         IF t_TotalSize < l_amount THEN
--         dbms_output.put_line('0 blob:'||ls_file_name);
--         
--          dbms_output.put_line('length:'||t_TotalSize);
--                UTL_FILE.put_raw (l_file, l_buffer);
--                UTL_FILE.fflush (l_file);

--         ELSE
             WHILE t_position < t_TotalSize
              LOOP
                 BEGIN
                 dbms_output.put_line(' blob:'||ls_file_name);
                    DBMS_LOB.read (l_blob, l_amount, t_position,  l_buffer);
                    UTL_FILE.put_raw (l_file, l_buffer);
                    UTL_FILE.fflush (l_file);
                    t_position := t_position + l_amount;
                    t_remain := t_remain - l_amount;

                    IF t_remain < 32767
                    THEN
                       l_amount := t_remain;
                    END IF;

                 EXCEPTION

                    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
                    THEN
                       NULL;
                 END;

              END LOOP;

--         END IF;

       UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(l_file);
       DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY (lclob_file);

    EXCEPTION

       --Exception to handle Invalid Path
       WHEN UTL_FILE.Invalid_path
           THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Invalid Dir');
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Directory Error: '||ls_file_name );            

       --Exception to handle Invalid Operation
       WHEN UTL_FILE.Invalid_operation
           THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Invalid operation');
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File Error write_bio_blob_to_file: '||ls_file_name ); 

        WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                err_code := SQLCODE;
                err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Others ');
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('File Error others: '||ls_file_name ); 

              INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL */ INTO image_null_log2
                VALUES(ls_pin_ref,ls_msisdn,ls_file_name,l_blob,err_code,err_msg);

          COMMIT;

    END write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26;

    /*
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Procedure Name: exp_bio_blob_to_file_mar26
    Procedure Description : This Procedure is used to export images.
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    PROCEDURE exp_bio_blob_to_file_mar26
    AS


        TYPE BioCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
        bio_cv BioCurTyp; 

        -- Table type that can hold information about owc_isl_data_test
        TYPE BioList_tab IS TABLE OF CUSTOMER_BIOMETRIC%ROWTYPE;
        BiometricInfo BioList_tab;

        start_time    number;
        end_time    number;
        l_diff        number;

    BEGIN

       --Truncating Image Log1 table
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'truncate table Image_Log3';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'truncate table Image_null_log3';

      start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

      --create a cursor that select all biometric data
      OPEN bio_cv FOR
                    SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS*/ *
                       FROM CUSTOMER_BIOMETRIC
                            WHERE rownum<1000000;


      --fetching biometric data from cursor in bulk of 1000
      FETCH bio_cv BULK COLLECT INTO BiometricInfo LIMIT 700000;
        CLOSE bio_cv;

        /* Export images from owc_isl_data_test table then write correspoding image to directory 
        to MIGRATION_2 which I mapped to ojecmtst01 path /ecm/digital/migration */

        FOR i IN BiometricInfo.FIRST .. BiometricInfo.LAST LOOP

          write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pinref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).PHOTO_PERSON,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN ||'_PT_05.jpg');
          write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pinref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).FINGPRNT_LEFT_THUMB,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN ||'_LT_05.wsq');
          write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pinref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).FINGPRNT_LEFT_INDEX,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN ||'_LF_05.wsq');
          write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pinref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).FINGPRNT_RIGHT_THUMB,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN ||'_RT_05.wsq');
          write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pinref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).FINGPRNT_RIGHT_INDEX,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN ||'_RF_05.wsq');

          --write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pin_ref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).PASSPORT_PHOTO,BiometricInfo(i).msisdn||'_PP_05.jpg');
          --write_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 (BiometricInfo(i).pin_ref,BiometricInfo(i).MSISDN,BiometricInfo(i).CER_IMG_DATA,BiometricInfo(i).msisdn||'_CI_05.jpg');

        END LOOP;


        COMMIT;

        end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
        l_diff := (end_time-start_time)/100;

        INSERT INTO time_log 
            VALUES(l_diff);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('start time ' || to_char(start_time));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('end time ' || to_char(end_time));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Elapsed  time ' || l_diff ||'sec'); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('end loop');

    EXCEPTION

    --Exception to handle Invalid Path
        WHEN UTL_FILE.Invalid_path
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Invalid Dir');

        --Exception to handle Invalid Operation
        WHEN UTL_FILE.Invalid_operation
            THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Invalid operation');     
         WHEN OTHERS
             THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Others '||SQLCODE||SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200)); 

    END exp_bio_blob_to_file_mar26;                                                            


End biometric_blob_to_file_april28;
/
```

Answering Ben's question

I am not sure what is the best way to parallise. I tried parallelism as by breaking the records into 100 000 ranges  but could not get it working properly. I did the following

1. Inside the same package, I created the procedure called exp_bio_blob_to_file_1_mar26. This procedure is similar to  exp_bio_blob_to_file_mar26 except for the below SQL

   --selecting records between 100 001 and 200000 */
         OPEN bio_cv FOR
                   SELECT      MSISDN             ,

                               PINREF            ,
                               PHOTO_PERSON          ,
                               FINGPRNT_LEFT_THUMB            ,
                               FINGPRNT_LEFT_INDEX             ,
                               FINGPRNT_RIGHT_THUMB           ,
                               FINGPRNT_RIGHT_INDEX

                     FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM rnum
                             FROM (SELECT  /*+ FIRST_ROWS*/ * 
                                     FROM CUSTOMER_BIOMETRIC) a
                            --ending point for selection of records within range
                            WHERE ROWNUM <= 200000)
                              --starting point for selecting records within range
                       WHERE rnum >= 100001;
2. set serveroutput on

   DECLARE
    jobnumber33 number; 
    jobnumber44 number;

   start_time    number;
    end_time    number;
    l_diff        number;
   BEGIN
     start_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
      dbms_job.submit(jobnumber33, 'begin biometric_blob_to_file_mar28.exp_bio_blob_to_file_mar26; dbms_output.put_line(''test1''); end;' );
      commit;
      dbms_job.submit(jobnumber44, 'begin biometric_blob_to_file_mar28.exp_bio_blob_to_file_1_mar26; dbms_output.put_line(''test2''); end;' );
      commit;
     dbms_job.run(jobnumber33);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Submitted Job ' || jobnumber33);

   dbms_job.run(jobnumber44);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Submitted Job ' || jobnumber44 );

   end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
      l_diff := (end_time-start_time)/100;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Elapsed  time ' || l_diff ||'sec');

   END;
   /

The first job will be executed fine but the second job will go straight in "OTHERS" section without executing. I am not sure why.. I am currently trying to create 2 different tables each holding separate range of records to be exported.

Answering Jeffrey's question

3. disk IO might be  the bottleneck. I will ask the Linux team to provide the disk IO stats but it would also be good I could get the parallelism once the disk IO is ruled out not be bottleneck

I just got disk io stats below. I looks like disk io is not the bottleneck

```
root@owcm880 # zpool iostat owcmigration 3
                 capacity     operations    bandwidth
pool          alloc   free   read  write   read  write
------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      5    393   140K
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0     65      0   881K
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
owcmigration  6.20G   289G      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Can you parallelise?

Comment: I'd do some profiling to see where the time is going - either on the query (probably not), the `DBMS_LOB.read` (maybe) or the file writing (`UTL_FILE.put_raw` or `UTL_FILE.fflush`). If the bottleneck is at the file writing stage, I'd look at the disk IO activity at the OS level to see if there's capacity there - and if so, Ben's idea to parallelise may make sense.

Comment: Just a tip: editing your question doesn't cause it to pop up in my notifications - but adding a comment does. :)

Comment: If the disk IO is not saturated, then yep dividing up the work and running them in parallel would be a good idea to try.

Comment: This looks like an Oracle bug to me. I see other posts for people with similar slowness issues. If I look at my own issue the first 128kb file takes 7 seconds and then it becomes incrementally slower. The 20th 128kb file takes 3 minutes.

Comment: Found my issue. The second parameter to dbms_lob.read is an input and output parameter. So if the last read is say 3 bytes then it becomes 3 and starts reading 3 bytes at a time for all subsequent files. Simply resetting it to 32767 at the beginning made it complete in 2 seconds